# Dapper.Contrib can't insert into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, dapper, dapper-contrib

I can't insert data into my database because it says that the ID can't be null and I'm inserting the ID. Also it does not work when I don't specify the ID and leave the autonumeration in DB settings.

This is my code:

```
using Dapper;
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Students;Integrated Security=True";

InsertSingleStudent();

void InsertSingleStudent()
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        Student student = new Student()
        {
            FirstName = "William",
            LastName = "Shakespeare",
            Semester = 1,
            Id = 1,
            BirthDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 1),
            University="UBB",
            Year = new DateTime(2022,1,1)
        };

        db.Insert<Student>(student);
    }
}
```

The exact error is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Students.dbo.Students'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: What does the class `Student.Id` property look like? Also is the `Id` column in the database an identity or something that auto populates that field?

Comment: looks like identity issue i.e you are trying to insert id in an identiy column. Can you share schema of the table `Student` for better understanding ?